# How to restrict public image url into private url in google app engine - java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

https://lh6.ggpht.com/KZRgvctAGfz-TAWDvnYCLu1-DAv-DMzPICa8t_Xyta77YtFen3UsVjJrEiaQkNBooQCqmobvvUoUg0znWPn96g we can access by who logged in my app. but now this is public.

Answer (score 1):

This is not not really AppEngine specific question as the image is not served by AppEngine servers. It looks it is hosted on Google+.

You have to go to the source of the image an make it private there, or restrict it to certain Google Accounts.

Another option would be to have your AppEngine app download this image, and serve it from there. That way the original URL of the image would not be published. And this way you can make security checks and deny serving the image if an authorized user is not logged in.